# Why import statements with parentheses?

Tags: python, import, parentheses

Lately have seen imports like this

```
from module import (function, another_function, 
                    another_function)
```

Seemingly this has been done to be able to stretch the `import` statement over more than one line. In cases like this I usually just import like so

```
from module import function, another_function, \
            another_function
```

What exactly are the parentheses doing in this case and are they considered to be bad practice?

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: See also [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), which introduced this syntax.

Answer (score 87):

As [PEP 8 states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.