# declaring classes from imported modules in python

Tags: python, class, import

In python you have to use

```
import <module>
```

to import a file with classes.

Imagine the module contains multiple classes

And now I want to declare an object

```
x = module.object1Name(parameter1,parmeter2)
```

**How can I declare that object without having to access it through module?**
(So like this below)

```
x = object1Name(parameter1,parameter2)
```

Also I do not want to use the following because it would mean I would have to do that for every class.

```
from <module> import <objectName>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following statement, that will import everything from the module:

```py
from <module> import *
```

But it is **not a good practice**, for some reasons:

- Your code must import only what you uses.
- The zen of python says "explicit is better than implicit", so if you want to use something, you need to import it explicitly.
- Improve the readability of your code.

I suggest to use the explicit imports in what you want to use.

```py
from <module> import <object1>, <object2>
```

Or, like below:

```py
from <module> import (
    <object1>,
    <object2>,
    <object3>,
    <object4>
)
```

Comment: Thank you. What does the '*' mean (does it mean all?)

Comment: Also why is it bad practice? Is it because of readability and understanding

Comment: Yes, it means that python will import everything from the module.

Comment: The idea of the bad practice is that your code must import only what you uses. Furthermore, the zen of python says "explicit is better than implicit". If you need to use something more, you need to import it explicitly. This also improve the readability as you said.

Comment: pontual ?= one-off

Comment: With pontual, I want to say explicitly what you want. May be one, two, or more objects from the module.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple `from <module> import <objectName>` statements with commas and parentheses.

For example:

`from <module> import <objectNameA>, <objectNameB>`

or

`from <module> import (<objectNameA>, <objectNameB>)`

The latter will work across multiple lines ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534027/why-import-statements-with-parentheses)).

Using `import * from <module>` (import everything from `<module>`) [is bad](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/) because it risks overriding functions, classes, and variables from other modules, and it violates the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) "better to be explicit" value.